# gdb scripting restart continue while loop

Tags: gdb

What is the equivalent of continue in gdb scripts?
I tried using loop_continue but it didn't work. Gdb threw error saying undefined command.

I want something like

```
    while $thr
     if $thr->procedureId != 28
        set $thr = $thr->cnext
         loop_continue; // this doesn't work
     end
     print $thr
     set $thr = $thr->cnext
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here, surprisingly, is the `;`.  For me this causes gdb to say:

> Undefined command: "loop_continue".  Try "help".

However, if I leave out the `;`, it works:

```
(gdb) set $x = 0
(gdb) while $x < 5
 >if $x < 3
  >set $x = 72
  >loop_continue
  >end
 >end
(gdb) print $x
$1 = 72
```